Anchor build dependency issue
anchor build
error: not a directory: '/home/emperor/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.18.18/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/lib'

I have tried to install the latest versions of rust, anchor and solana so they can be compatible, but I don't know what to do about path issues which I suspect

try deleting your cache and re-installing solana using the anza install script -> sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/stable/install)

https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/13174/2848 this is a similar question but this error typically means that Anchor is expecting a directory to exist at the specified path, but it does not.

i recently integrated into ubuntu, heres my guide below.


Solana CLI:
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.18.26/install)"
Rust:
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
then -->    source $HOME/.cargo/env
Anchor:
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor anchor-cli --locked
Cargo:
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor anchor-cli --locked
Verfiy All:
After Solana CLI installation finishes, run these commands:
rustc --version
solana --version
cargo --version
anchor --version
node -v
npm -v
Versions:
Installed Components
Rust: Version 1.82.0
Solana CLI: Version 1.18.26
Anchor CLI: Version 0.30.1
Node.js: Version 23.1.0
npm: Version 10.9.0
